uniqueness of the inversion to Riemann-Stieltjes integral equation
I believe that if, for a Riemann-Stieltjes integral with $h(s)$ of bounded variation,
$$ \int_0^1 s^\alpha dh(s) = 0 \qquad\text{for any }\alpha\in(\alpha_0,\alpha_1) ,
\tag{1}\label{eq1}$$
then $h$ is actually zero.
But is it really true and why is it so?
In other words, how do I show that the eventual solution $w(s)$ (now a non-decreasing cumulative distribution function) to the equation
$$ f(\alpha) = \int_0^1 s^\alpha dw(s)
,$$
for function $f$ given on (any) open interval $(\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$,
is unique?
I only remember from school that a continuous function $g(x)$ has to be zero if
$$ \int_0^1 x^n g(x) dx = 0 \qquad\text{with $n=0,1,\ldots$} ,$$
where the argument was the density of polynomials in the space of continuous functions.
Does the same idea apply here somehow, or is this case different?
Also, if we would consider discrete approximations to $w(s)$, e.g. in $N$ fixed points $s_j\in(0,1)$, and with $N$ selected $\alpha_i$, $i,j=1,\ldots,N$, then the matrix $a_{ij} = s_j^{\alpha_i}$ in the algebraic problem
$$ \sum_j s_j^{\alpha_i} w_j = f_i $$
has linearly independent rows...

Imho the claim has to be that $h$ is a constant function.

Oh yes, or it should have been specified that $h(0)=0$ is assumed.

Coming back to $(0,\infty)$ by $x=-\log s$ and calling $\mu(dx)$ the image of the measure $h(ds)$ by $s\mapsto x$ your question is equivalent to
'If I know the function $L(\alpha)=\int _0^{\infty}e^{-\alpha x}\mu(dx)$ on $(\alpha_0,\alpha_1)$ do I know $\mu?$ Answer: Yes. Proof.1)  Pick $\alpha_2\in (\alpha_0,\alpha_1).$

Observe the fact that $\alpha\mapsto L(\alpha)$ is
real analytic on $(\alpha_0,\alpha_1).$

if $z=\alpha+it$ observe that $L(z)$ is well defined on the strip $(\alpha_0,\alpha_1)\times iR$ since it is an analytic function, unique since known for $t=0$ (use the principle of isolated zeros, see Rudin Complex Analysis). In particular $L(\alpha_2+it)$ is the Fourier transform of the BOUNDED positive measure $e^{-\alpha_2 x}\mu(dx)$

the Levy theorem says that the Fourier transform of a probability characterizes the probability. Apply this to the probability $e^{-\alpha_2 x}\mu(dx)/L(\alpha_2).$ So you know $\mu.$


